# Assistance with optimizing below MySql procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, random

MySql - innodb_version  5.7.33

I working on a stored procedure which will be called periodically (lets say once a month) to populate a table with list of string in one column and with static values in other column.
The table also has

- ID column (AUTO_INCREMENT) and
- timestamp column (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

The string is a concatenation of fixed characters plus integers (lets say 10).
This integer has to be non repetitive random within the range.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`db`@`%` PROCEDURE `InsertRandom`(IN NumRows INT, IN MinVal INT, IN MaxVal INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE UniqueId INT(15);
    SET i = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;
    WHILE i <= NumRows DO
        SET UniqueId = concat('ABC', MinVal + CEIL(RAND() * (MaxVal - MinVal)));
        IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT UNIQUE_ID FROM MY_TABLE WHERE UNIQUE_ID = UniqueId) THEN
            INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (`UNIQUE_ID`, `STATE`, `RANGE_ID`) VALUES (UniqueId, 'new', '100');
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
    COMMIT;
END
```

The range (minVal & maxVal) will be 1 million for every procedure call.

For example,

```
CALL InsertRandom(1000000, 10000000,11000000);
```

The table will be purged once in 5 months retaining 1 month of data, so we can assume there will be at about 5 million records at a point when this procedure will executed and the usage of select inside loop is not optimal so please suggest an alternative approach.

(From Comment:)

The goal is to have a table with unique IDs within a given range. These shouldn't be in sequence. The range is in minimum of a million at time and maximum of 10 mill. Chunks of which will be loaded into server's memory for further processing. I'm interested in options to populate this table efficiently.

Comment: Dump the select and use insert ignore?

Comment: Great, thank you @Shadow . This really helps.
Updated the procedure accordingly. 
Just that it messes with the ID column which is defined as auto increment. There are gaps.

Comment: So what if there are gaps in the auto increment column? That's perfectly normal!

Comment: Back up.  Please state the goal, rather than ask "how to fix this design".

Comment: The goal is to have a table with unique IDs within a given range. These shouldn't be in sequence. The range is in minimum of a million at time and maximum of 10 mill. Chuncks of which will be loaded into servers memory for further processing.  I'm interested in options to populate this table efficiently. As stated in original question this table will be purged periodically.  Thank you for your assistance in advance.

Comment: @RickJames
Any ideas based on the goal elaborated above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stored procedure will found a bottle neck trying to fill some holes.
What about to pre-generate the numbers starting MinVal and insert those in a random order, take a look:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers(
    `UNIQUE_ID` INT,
    `STATE` VARCHAR(50),
    `RANGE_ID` VARCHAR(50)
);


DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS InsertRandom $$
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertRandom (IN NumRows INT, IN MinVal INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT;
    DECLARE UniqueId INT;
    SET i = 0;
    
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS numbers_tmp(
        UNIQUE_ID int, 
        RAND_VAL double, 
        INDEX(RAND_VAL)
    );
    
    START TRANSACTION;
    
    WHILE i < NumRows DO
        INSERT INTO numbers_tmp(UNIQUE_ID,RAND_VAL) 
        VALUES (i + MinVal ,rand());
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
    
    INSERT INTO numbers (`UNIQUE_ID`, `STATE`, `RANGE_ID`) 
    SELECT `UNIQUE_ID`, 'new', '100'
    FROM numbers_tmp
    ORDER BY RAND_VAL; /* <-- THIS  */
        
    COMMIT;
    
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE numbers_tmp;
END $$
DELIMITER ;


CALL InsertRandom(100, 500);

mysql> select  * from numbers;
+-----------+-------+----------+
| UNIQUE_ID | STATE | RANGE_ID |
+-----------+-------+----------+
|       575 | new   | 100      |
|       523 | new   | 100      |
|       560 | new   | 100      |
|       537 | new   | 100      |
|       526 | new   | 100      |
|       549 | new   | 100      |
|       598 | new   | 100      |
|       552 | new   | 100      |
|       555 | new   | 100      |
|       581 | new   | 100      |
...
```

At this point. maybe is a good idea just insert the values in your main table and order by some rand inserted number. I don't know.

Comment: (There are much faster ways to generate a table of integers like `numbers_tmp`.)

Comment: Thank you Ivan for the effort. This indeed avoided gaps in the sequence between the min & max range i had in my query. 
Appreciate your effort.

Comment: @RickJames
Some hints please? So i can use it for further improvisation. 
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert a bunch of random numbers into a table.
2. Remove from that table any numbers that are currently in use.
3. When you need a number, take the 'next' number from that table, then delete it.
4. Check each night to see if the table is 'nearly' empty.  If so, rerun the above steps.

Slightly different:

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    number INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    UNIQUE(number)    -- avoids dups, see IGNORE below
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Do this nightly, not monthly:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Numbers (number)
    SELECT FLOOR(9000000 * RAND() + 1000000)  -- for range of 1M to 10M
              AS number
        FROM MainTable   -- any table with lots of rows
        HAVING NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM MainTable
                WHERE Numbers.number = MainTable.number )
        LIMIT 12345;  -- enough to last 3 days, not a month
```

To get a new, unique, `number` (pseudo code):

```
BEGIN;
$number = SELECT number FROM Numbers LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
DELETE FROM Numbers WHERE number = $number;
COMMIT;
```

Then proceed to use $number in MainTable.